# Generating csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, faker

I want to write a program that generate N number of csv files using python and I want to add an option to add  a custom schema to generate the headers and values. the csv file should have 5 columns and and N number rows.  Country,  Capital city, population , Square meter, Continent and each column could have have different datatype.

I used the [faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) python package to generate a couple of such data but was not able to figure out on how to add the custom schema and datatype of each column.

Comment: look at Example 2 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-csv-files-python/

Comment: CSV files have only one data type, text.

Answer (score 0):

use "pandas" to make schema
from there you can make .csv